# Admin Grid - Remove columns from export

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, export, order-grid

I am in a situation, where I need to display an **email_address1** in grid, and during export have to use other one (**email_address2**).
For this I have added two columns in grid, with **email_address1** is visible in grid and with **email_address2** will not, as shown

```
        $this->addColumn('customer_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer'),
            'index' => 'email_address1',
            'width' => '60',
            'type' => 'text',
            'filter_index' => 'email_address1'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('customer_name_ordered', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer'),
            'index' => 'email_address2',
            'column_css_class'=>'no-display',
            'header_css_class'=>'no-display',
            'width' => '60',
            'type' => 'text',
            'filter_index' => 'email_address2'
        ));
```

During export (csv or xml), both columns are being exported, how can I stop column with **email_address1** from being exported, or please suggest an other solution.

My export action for **CSV** is like

```
   public function exportCsvAction() {
        $fileName = 'sales_order_items.csv';
        $content = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('salesorderitemgrid/adminhtml_order_items_grid')->getCsv();

        $this->_sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content);
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got it, if set **is_system** true for a column, it will not be exported.So

```
    $this->addColumn('customer_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer'),
        'index' => 'email_address1',
        'width' => '60',
        'type' => 'text',
        'is_system' => true,
        'filter_index' => 'email_address1'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('customer_name_ordered', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer'),
        'index' => 'email_address2',
        'column_css_class'=>'no-display',
        'header_css_class'=>'no-display',
        'width' => '60',
        'type' => 'text',
        'filter_index' => 'email_address2'
    ));
```

Now column with **email_address1** will not be exported.

Comment: @ Abdul Ghaffar : I am using this method https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/171754/51361  for adding custom field on sales order grid. but when i export, the custom added column values not exported, how can i solve this error.

Comment: @Rathinam is your issue resolved?